# Error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to display a RecyclerView on a fragment using FireBase Database, but for some unknown reason its giving me this error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; Im pretty sure im actually attaching the adapter, here's the code:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment currentFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            currentFragment = new MapsFragment();
            changeFragment(currentFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_bookmarkList:
                currentFragment = new ListaFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_mapa:
                currentFragment = new MapsFragment();
                break;

        }
        changeFragment(currentFragment);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void changeFragment(Fragment currentFragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,currentFragment).commit();
    }
    
}
```

ListaFragment (the one that should display the Recycler):

```
public class ListaFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.RecyclerItemClick{


    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    public ListaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container, false);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Marcador");
        
        recycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyler);

        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Marcador> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Marcador>()
                .setQuery(myRef, Marcador.class).build();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(options,this);

        recycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        return v;

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        myAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        myAdapter.stopListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void itemClick(Marcador marcador) {

    }
}
```

And the adapter i've done (im skipping the xml's since they are quite simple):

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Marcador,MyAdapter.MarcadorHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private RecyclerItemClick itemClick;

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Marcador> options, RecyclerItemClick itemClick) {
        super(options);
        this.itemClick = itemClick;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MarcadorHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Marcador model) {
        final Marcador marcador = getItem(position);
        holder.textViewNom.setText(model.getNom());
        holder.textViewLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(model.getLatitude()));
        holder.textViewLongitude.setText(model.getLongitude());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemClick.itemClick(marcador);
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MarcadorHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recylcer_view_item,parent,false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new MarcadorHolder(v);
    }

    public class MarcadorHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewNom;
        TextView textViewLatitude;
        TextView textViewLongitude;

        public MarcadorHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewNom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNom);
            textViewLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLatitud);
            textViewLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLongitut);
        }

    }

    public interface RecyclerItemClick {
        void itemClick(Marcador marcador);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can give me an answer of why this is happening, since i've checked other options and i can't really get through it.

XML's attached of fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ListaFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="545dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML attached of item of recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" android:background="#CDCDCD" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNom"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLatitud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="latitud" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLongitut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="longitut" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do use below lines

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer more clearly? like how using this code is different from OP's attempt?

Comment: We always need a layout manager for recyclerview as you have added in your code, but you have not added orientation in your code. Try to use above line of code and see if these are working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Fragment API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#oncreateview):

> It is recommended to only inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated(View, Bundle).

So in `onCreateView` you should only inflate your layout hence the `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container, false);` you used and move logic of your code to `onViewCreated` and the reason you facing `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached;` is because you're trying to setting adapter for your recyclerview before even creation/inflation of the view which is failing to complete therefore after the creation/inflation is done there's no adapter attached to recyclerview.

Answer (score -1):

It is generally recommended to not initialize the component using `findViewById` in **`onViewCreated()`** as per the [The Google Developer Documents.](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

> You should inflate your layout in onCreateView but shouldn't
> initialize other views using findViewById in onCreateView.

Because in this method not every View is not Properly initialized. So, prefer to use `onViewCreated()` to get your view's Id and do setUp the UI.

Comment: Can you point out where exactly in documentation says 'You should inflate your layout in onCreateView but shouldn't initialize other views using findViewById in onCreateView.' ?

Comment: I think my link is already pointing out the same thing though.

Comment: I even tried with onViewCreated() and sadly no luck :/

Comment: can you also attached the xml file then?

Comment: @animusmind i have added now the XML (fragment+item) in the message of the post, maybe im missing something

Comment: are you sure that you're getting the data from databases and then your listener start to listen. and also make sure that whatever format you are passing are you able to access your data from Firebase in similar way.

Comment: at least provide some explanation before downvoting guys.